# Design guideline for saving big byte stream in c#

Tags: c#

I have an application where I am receiving big byte array very fast around per 50 miliseconds.

The byte array contains some information like file name etc. The data (byte array ) may come from several sources.

Each time I receive the data, I have to find the file name and save the data to that file name.

I need some guide lines to how should I design it so that it works efficient.

Following is my code...

```
public class DataSaver
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, FileStream> _dictFileStream;

        public static void SaveData(byte[] byteArray)
        {
            string fileName = GetFileNameFromArray(byteArray);
            FileStream fs = GetFileStream(fileName);
            fs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        private static FileStream GetFileStream(string fileName)
        {
            FileStream fs;
            bool hasStream = _dictFileStream.TryGetValue(fileName, out fs);
            if (!hasStream)
            {
                fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append);
                _dictFileStream.Add(fileName, fs);
            }
            return fs;
        }

        public static void CloseSaver()
        {
            foreach (var key in _dictFileStream.Keys)
            {
                _dictFileStream[key].Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I improve this code ? I need to create a thread maybe to do the saving.

Comment: You can start by removing `static` and writing proper OO code.

Comment: @Jon:   Any problem with static code ?

Comment: Cross-posted to Programmers, migrated to Code Review.  You can find the one we're keeping here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18266/design-guideline-for-saving-big-byte-stream-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine a threadpool where for each request a thread would take over and save the data or do what has to be done, and continue waiting for new requests. Consider using the TPL or the older ThreadPool.